# Is drawing human is haram in islam without selling purpose or intention of compete with Allah?

Tags: sharia, islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis, islamic-scholar

Drawing is just my hobby. After drawing I like to store them in my closet. I heard that drawing human is haram because it can lead to worshipping and it also means copying Allah's creation. But I don’t want to sell or publish my art and also I don’t have any intention to compete with Allah. Is it still haram? I just like to draw human like celebrity or human from my visual concepts.

Answer (score -2):

It depends. If you are drawing a human figure in order to pray to it, then it is indeed taboo as Islam is strongly against icons. However, doing it as a hobby is perfectly acceptable if you have innocuous intentions.